# What is the difference between a rest api and web api

Tags: api, web-services, rest

I want to know what’s the difference between a web service (web api)  and a rest api

I have learnt till now only GET and POST methods in backend to communicate with my apps but people always talk about PUT DELETE UPDATE & REST etc I am unable to understand the benefits and meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between a rest api and web api

Neither of these terms is well enough defined to assert with any confidence "the" difference.

[REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5); the most important application of that style is the world wide web.  The web has been so catastrophically successful that there really hasn't been a second REST application - if you need what REST offers, you use the web, because the hard work has already been done for you.

> I am unable to understand the benefits and meaning.

For every standardized HTTP method, you can use the [HTTP method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) to find the reference that defines the meaning of the method.

Most of the methods that people talk about on a regular basis have their meanings defined by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3).

The benefit comes from the fact that the meanings of the different methods are standardized; the provide certain semantic guarantees that allow *general purpose* components to do clever things.

For example, knowing that a method has [idempotent semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) means that we can resend the http request when we don't get a response the first time, this is an important constraint when your network is unreliable.  Because that's true of all idempotent requests, regardless of which URI is being targeted, we can build a retry into the browser.

It may help to think about POST as "the" basic message, and all of the others as being specializations

- GET is a specialization of POST that is used to retrieve copies of representations
- HEAD is a specialization of GET that is used to retrieve metadata
- PUT is a specialization of POST that is used for "upserting" new representations
- PATCH is a specialization of POST that applies patch documents to a resource